# CSS float left with margin auto on div?

Tags: html, css

hello friends can i set `float:left` with the `margin:auto`

this is my html code

```
<div class='gallary'>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
</div>
```

my css code this is not working.

```
.gallary{
     width:100%;
 }
 .gallary div{
       float:left;
       margin:0 auto;
  }
```

please help.
Thank you.

Comment: You want to center divs inside .gallary?

Comment: @marcelo2605 yes dear but with float left.

Comment: The inner divs have fixed width?

Comment: yes dear inner div have fixed with is 217px.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this is very help fully. i hop this is used full for you.

```
.gallary{
 width:100%;
 }

.gallary div{
       vertical-align:top;
       display:inline-block;
       margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

just use inline-block instead of float

```
.gallary div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `display: inline-block;` to maintain the divs at the same line and `text-align:center;` do align to the center:

Here's the fix:
http://jsfiddle.net/4xxvb/3/

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and got it working, all you have to do is:

```
.gallary{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: Center;
}
.gallary div{
    display: Inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Can you add some more details, possibly explain your code and why it works? (Edit your answer, don't comment, thanks)